# puxar dado de uma terceira tabela numa relação simples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-record

Oi! Eu tenho 3 tabelas. estudoanimais, espécies e procedências, onde :

```
estudoanimais belongs_to especie
estudoanimais has_many_procedencias
especie has_many estudoanimais
procedencia belongs_to estudoanimal
```

No momento que eu crio uma procedência, eu posso associar isso a uma espécie, puxada de um select da seguinte forma:

```
f.select :estudoanimais_id, Estudoanimal.all.collect{|ea| [ea.especie.nome,ea.id]}
```

O que eu gostaria é de mostrar o nome dessa espécie escolhida em vez de seu id nas telas da procedência. No console, estou tentando fazer da seguinte forma:

```
p=Procedencia.first
nome = p.estudoanimal.especie.nome
```

e ele fala que não pode trazer esse nome por causa que é um valor nulo, mas se eu coloco:

```
p.estudoanimais_id
```

ele traz o valor da id da espécie que escolhi na hora de criar uma procedência. Onde estou errando?

Comment: Já tentou usar o `collection_select`?
Funcionou no ultimo projeto Rails que eu fiz

Answer (score 0):

Ficou um pouco complicado, mas você não está trazendo trocando o ID pelo NOME?

```
f.select :estudoanimais_id, Estudoanimal.all.collect{|ea| [ea.id, ea.especie.nome]}
```